# How to use GAE deferred functionality?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue, deferred

I do the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

def send_message(client_id, message):
    logging.info("sending message...")

class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, field_name):
        ...
        scUpdate = {
                       'val': value,
                       'name': field_name_converted
                   }
        message = simplejson.dumps(scUpdate)                      
        deferred.defer(send_message, client_id, message, _countdown=random.randrange(0, 5, 1))
```

and getting

```
PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

What is wrong here?

Upd. looks like the problem is the same as described there - [PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'Migrate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770669/permanenttaskfailure-module-object-has-no-attribute-migrate) - but I don't understand how to fix that.

Comment: I thought Nick's comment to that linked answer was quite clear - you can't use a function that's defined in a module you use directly as a handler from app.yaml. Move it into a different file and import it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, is it the only possible approach? So, I will have the same functionality in 2 different files? Would it be better to use directly Task Queue instead?

Comment: Why would it be in two files? Move the code to a separate file, don't copy it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I wanted to say that `MyHandler` will be in one file, when `send_message` should be in the second file. Doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred:

Limitations of the deferred library

- You can't call a method in the request handler module.

The function that is called via deferred.defer **must not** be in the same
module like the request handler where deferred.defer is called.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've used `taskqueue` with `countdown` instead and it works well.